# How to use the datagrid field to filter the data

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagrid, dataview

I have created a vb.net project with several forms and now I have a question. I want to filter the data stored in a `datagridview` according to the months.

Consider the data as given below

```
 CUSTOMERNAME    MONEY     DATE 

 RAJA            1000      5/22/2011
 RAM             15872     12/28/2010
 RESHMA          12542     10/15/2010
 POONAM          12345     2/25/2011
 SANDEEP         54543     5/15/2011
```

Consider a combobox with a list of months (1 2 3 ... 12) , when the user chooses a month, I want to filter the data in the `datagridview` according to the chosen month.

If the user selects 5 it must filter the result and show only

```
 RAJA            1000      5/22/2011
 SANDEEP         54543     5/15/2011
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is fairly general here are a couple of links that will get you in the right general question. If you want more specific help you can Edit your question and include what you've tried so far.

Here's an article on the [DataView.RowFilter Property](http://DataView.RowFilter%20Property)

Here's a [linq solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb738016#sumsimp) to sum a column on a dataset, it far from the only way you can do this.

Comment: Sir its say the link does not exist and the next link linqsolution i cant understand how to do can u help me.. or explain with an example acutaly i am new to vb.net i am self studying so plz can u help me............